# Basic notation problem for ordered list with elements from another list

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am not sure about how to formalise a solution that I found to a software engineering application that I wrote. In a few words I have a set of events $(E_1,...,E_N)$ and a library of actions AL which contains K actions $AL = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_K)$. Each event is made of a ordered sequence of actions from AL, for instance $E_1 = (a_2, a_3, a_7)$, $ E_2 = (a_5, a_4)$, $E_3 = (a_9)$, and so on.

My question is: **How would you write the generic i-th event?**

I came up with something like $E_i = (a_{i1}, a_{i2}, a_{i3})$ but this comes with two issues:

1. How would I link the element $a_{ij}$ to the action $a_k \in AL$?
2. How would I state that $a_{ij}$ can be the same as $a_{pq}$ with $(i,j) \neq (p,q)$ if they point to the same $a_k$?

Comment: Let $A = \{a_1, \dots, a_K\}$ be a set of actions. We have $N$ events $E_1, \dots, E_N$, where each event $E_i$ is a finite sequence of actions, so $E_i \in A^*$. We denote the length of the $i$-th event as $M_i$ and denote its component actions as $E_i = (e_{i,1}, e_{i,2}, \dots, e_{i, M_i})$.

Comment: Or, maybe better, let $A$ be a finite set of actions. We have $N$ events $E_1, \dots, E_N$, where each event $E_i$ is a finite sequence of actions, so $E_i \in A^*$. We denote the length of the $i$-th event as $M_i$ and denote its component actions as $E_i = (a_{i,1}, a_{i,2}, \dots, a_{i, M_i})$, where each $a_{i,j} \in A$.

Comment: That would work, thanks!